# "Hunk #1" message after apply a patch

Tags: ubuntu, patch

I am trying to apply a patch on Linux using `patch -p1 < name_of_a_patch.patch`

I get this line saying

```
patching file my_application.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 96 (offset -27 lines)
```

And I see a file `my_application.c.org`

What does this mean?

Comment: Please [format](http://superuser.com/help/formatting) your posts correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the file to be patched has changed slightly since the patch was created, but the specific section remained the same, `patch` can detect that and apply the patch appropriately.

The message you see means the file was successfully patched, but the first section that was patched was 27 lines earlier than was originally specified.

Comment: does it need manual review or is it safe to assume that patch applied correctly ?

Comment: In my experience, the "succeeded" message always means the patch applied correctly. I assume that `patch` is smart enough to give me an error if there are any issues.

Comment: But it's always a good idea to give a quick manual review.